# Single ipv6 from /64 subnet for squid proxy server

Tags: proxy, squid, ipv6

### **Skip This Section if You are Normal Human Being**

I read [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/622484/single-ipv6-from-64-subnet) where everyone who answered acted like they were from another planet. I see it sometimes, but not often, in tech forums. And this topic was closed without any help to the poor guy.

I hope this goes a bit better because it is exactly the same topic. I will try to predict the thinking that goes into *intricate avoidance* of answering ***the actually asked question***.

Please, no flaming! Yes, I realize this is free assistance, just as I have given on multiple occassions. That does not give a free pass to be rude and offensive, so please behave... even in subtle ways. Just be kind and straight forward. If you have nothing concrete to add don't say anything. Read the TOS.

### **PROBLEM DEFINED**

I have an ipv6 range assigned on Hertzner hosting. I have a dedicated self-managed server. I have just now installed the latest Squid Proxy as I have in the past on other servers. My previous config file had individual ipv6 addresses assigned to each port number. It was set up with ipv4 addresses pointing to one port each as well. So one port would be matched with an ipv4 AND an ipv6 address (one line in the config for ipv4 and one line for ipv6... same port).

Here is a sample:

```
tcp_outgoing_address 50.21.183.11 port1
tcp_outgoing_address 2607:f1c0:84d:b200:0:0:74:a9de port1
tcp_outgoing_address 74.208.147.124 port2
tcp_outgoing_address 2607:f1c0:84d:b284:d0eb:efbd:87bc:30a7 port2
tcp_outgoing_address 74.208.148.250 port3
tcp_outgoing_address 2607:f1c0:84d:b2eb:689b:37e1:713:f73f port3
```

My current Hertzner ipv6 range is 2a01:4f8:212:50d:: / 64  How do I assign individual ipv6 addresses from this to individual ports in the Squid Proxy config? I have a range, but how can I know the individual addresses in that range?

---

Sorry for the introductory part, but I hate wasting my time and other people's time with the terrible behavior so common online. I know it won't deter it, but who knows, maybe one or two will feel bad and not do it.

Answer (score 1):

You have that complete IPv6 range available on your box, that is about 2^64 addresses.

You can configure any IPv6 address(es) from the range on your box, and then use them in your Squid configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused what you are asking, but I would like to help. It looks like you have the config figured out, so are you just trying to understand IPv6?

If your question is just how to pick an address from the subnet, the valid IP addresses for that /64 are 2a01:4f8:212:50d:0000:0000:0000:0001 through 2a01:4f8:212:50d:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF:FFFF.

IPv6 works based on hexadecimal, which values range from 0 through F (0123456789ABCDEF). A through F represent 11 - 16. That means the the front end of your avaiable addresses, in order, would be

```
0001
0002 
0003 
0004 
0005 
0006 
0007 
0008 
0009 
000A 
000B
000C
000D
000E
000F
0010
0011
...
```

If this needs revision, or does not cover your question, please leave a comment.